# Unable to find solution to Parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate'

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, maven

I'm very new to Springboot and I've searched for the solution to be able to fix the error but with no avail.

I still keep getting this error:

````
```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in sample.ArticlesRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' in your configuration.
````

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprinboot_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sprinboot_Project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my ArticlesRepository:

```java
Here is my ArticlesRepository:
@Repository
public  class ArticlesRepository implements ArticledDao{


  public ArticlesRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Override
    public List<Articles> findAll() {
        return template.query("select * from article", new ArticlesRowMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteArticles(Articles articles) {
        final String sql = "delete from article where articleid=:articleid";
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("articleid", articles.getId());

        template.execute(sql,map,new PreparedStatementCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)
                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        });

    }

    }
```

Article Dao class:

```java
package sample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public interface ArticledDao {
    List<Articles> findAll();

    public void deleteArticles(Articles articles);
}
```

Here is my Main class:

```java
package sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="sample")
@EnableJpaRepositories("sample")
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/articles
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

I hope you can provide a solution that I've couldn't find in stackoverflow and I will be grateful for the help.

Github link: https://github.com/Editux/springboot/tree/main/sprinboot_project
The tutorial I was following : https://dzone.com/articles/bounty-spring-boot-and-postgresql-database

List of files:
[image]

Comment: @Deadpool I did that and I still face the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly I needed to remove this `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`  from application.properties to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `ArticlesRepository` has a field `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` Spring want to set dependency with type `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` for correctly creating `ArticlesRepository` but he can't find any bean with type NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.
You should declare one or more beans with type NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in your Spring context by using any of the possible annotations @Component or @Bean in the configuration class.

Comment: As per tutorial I declared Component in ServiceImp class. Unless I had to declare somewhere else but then I don't have a clue.

Comment: I have also included list of files

Answer (score 1):

DAO object should be an entity, not repository
also, in your repository class, you don't have to implement the default methods like findAll and delete...I'd completely rework your code to this:

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class ArticleDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;
    private boolean active;
    
    // getters and setters (or use Lombok)
}
```

**Repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<ArticleDAO, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: But doesnt' an entity  should a POJO class not a Dao? I just did according to this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-and-postgresql

Comment: I have also included list of files

Comment: I meant this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/bounty-spring-boot-and-postgresql-database

Comment: I'm not saying your approach is totally wrong, but I've the feeling you're trying to reinvent the wheel...this tutorial might be better for you - https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I managed to run the server and I will post the answer soon